# Set newly created file as variable in makefile

Tags: bash, variables, makefile, buildroot

I am trying to create a file and set the contents of a file to a variable but the variable is always seen as empty.

An example:

```
define FILE_VAR
    cat /output/1.txt >> /output/2.txt
    $(eval s := $(shell cat /output/2.txt)) 
    $(eval FILENAME_BIN=$(word 1, $(s)).$(word 2, $(s)).$(word 3, $(s)).bin) 
    $(eval FILENAME_JFFS2=$(word 1, $(s)).$(word 2, $(s)).$(word 3, $(s)).jffs2)        
endef
```

If `2.txt` exists before running this the variables will be set to the data prior to running make (not the new redirected data), if `2.txt` doesn't exist then the variables are not set. It looks like it is evaluating what the file is like when make is first run, which is not what I want...

Comment: Isn't this mostly a duplicate of [your earlier post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570930/using-eval-in-make-file)? Several comments made on that post apply to this one. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is highly recommended indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are unclear as to what is done by GNU make, and when, and what is done by the shell,
and when, to execute a recipe.

Anything anywhere in a makefile of the form `$(...)` is evaluated by `make`
unless it escaped as `$$(...)` in a shell command.

A shell command, unless in the context of the make-function `$(shell ...)` or
back-ticks can only be a command within a recipe:

```
target: [prerequisite...]
    command
    ...
```

The commands composing a recipe are executed in sequence, each in a distinct
shell, to execute the recipe.

Nothing of the unescaped form `$(...)` is a command in the command-sequence
of a recipe unless it is the expansion of a variable or macro you have defined that *expands* to a command.

A line in the scope of a target need not be a command or expand to a command. It
may also consist of an `$(...)` expression that expands to nothing,
and simply instructs `make` to do something, e.g.

```
$(info ...)
```

expands to nothing and tells `make` to print `...` on the standard output.

```
$(eval ...)
```

expands to nothing and tells `make` to evaluate `...`

This recipe has just two commands, not four:

```
target: prereq...
    $(eval TARGET=$@)
    command1
    $(info $(TARGET))
    command2
```

Any make-expressions, `$(...)` in the scope of a recipe are evaluated in
sequence when make decides to run the recipe *and the command-sequence is what
is left after they have all been evaluated*. Then
the command-sequence is run. For example:

**Makefile**

```
target:
    echo Hello > hello.txt
    $(info Begin {)
    $(eval s := $(shell cat hello.txt)) 
    $(eval WORD=$(word 1, $(s)))
    $(info [$(WORD)])
    $(info } End)
```

Run that:

```
$ make
Begin {
cat: hello.txt: No such file or directory
[]
} End
echo Hello > hello.txt
```

Observe that all of the make-expressions are evaluated *before* the
commands of the target are run.

Your `FILE_VAR` macro is evidently intended to be expanded in recipe scope, since the first line is a shell command.
The remaining lines must therefore achieve their purposes *by shell commands* if they depend upon the
the effects of running the first line. None of them does so. The remaining 3 lines
are evaluated before `2.txt` exists, if it doesn't already exist at make-time.

Comment: Thanks Mike, great answer. Never used make before so it was very informative. What I mainly take from ti to solve my problem is that the Make evaluates the expressions before I desire them to, so should do everything via shell. This is also why if my file does exist at make-time and is changed, I am reading the old values in the file.

Comment: Yes. It is nearly always right to make a recipe of lines that are shell
commands or expand to shell commands after expansion of the ordinary, global make-variables and macros. Cases in which [`$(eval ...)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html) is serviceable within a recipe are unusual. See [How make Reads a Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html)
and in general consult the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) for guidance.