# How can you export a variable to Make's 'shell' function?

Tags: gnu-make

Consider the following:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo in a.sh, BANANA=$BANANA
$ cat Makefile
.PHONY: foo
export BANANA = I am a banana

foo:
        $(eval F=`./a.sh`)  # BANANA is set in a.sh
        echo $F
        $(eval G=$(shell ./a.sh))  # BANANA is *not* set in a.sh
        echo $G
$ make
# BANANA is set in a.sh
echo `./a.sh`
in a.sh, BANANA=I am a banana
# BANANA is *not* set in a.sh
echo in a.sh, BANANA=
in a.sh, BANANA=
```

As demonstrated, the `export` directive to Make tells make to set the variable `BANANA` in the environment of its children.  But that setting does not apply to the `shell` function.  It does seem to apply to the backticks.  Is this a bug?  How can I easily set make variables to the environment of the `shell` function?

Note:

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.0
Built for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Well, I see why the backticks work, so that's a red-herring.

Comment: I guess there's no answer to the question of whether this is a bug or not as `$(shell)` is a gmake-only thing; `export`, OTOH, is under consideration to become a POSIX make feature (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html); my guess why BANANA isn't exported here is that it goes through two levels of child process creation, and isn't exported from the direct child process of the main make process to the ultimate `a.sh` child-child process

Comment: I suspect you're doing some other make stuff wrong. If all you really want to convince yourself of is that the `export` really works, you've put too many moving parts into your example. Just have the `foo` rule do one thing which is run a.sh. (Not with `eval` or `$(shell)`, just run it.) Perhaps you can have a.sh echo "$BANANA" to a file. You will then see that the export works. (Perhaps you will have other make issues, but you can similarly break each of them down.)

Answer (score 3):

First, be clear about the meaning of your recipe:

```
foo:
    $(eval F=`./a.sh`)  # BANANA is set in a.sh
    echo $F
    $(eval G=$(shell ./a.sh))  # BANANA is *not* set in a.sh
    echo $G
```

This recipe contains *two* (not *four*) commands:

```
foo:
    echo $F
    echo $G
```

and the two make-functions:

```
    $(eval F=`./a.sh`)
    $(eval G=$(shell ./a.sh))
```

will be evaluated, in that order, for the scope of the two-line recipe when `make` decides to
run it. If you are surpised by this point, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41609184/1362568)
and answer.

Be clear also that `F` and `G` are both *make* variables, not shell variables. You
only get away with referring to `$F` and `$G` rather than `$(F)` and `$(G)` thanks
to the last para of [6.1 Basics of Variable References](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reference.html#Reference)

> A dollar sign followed by a character other than a dollar sign, open-parenthesis or open-brace 
>   treats that single character as the variable name. Thus, you could reference the variable x with ‘$x’. 
>   However, this practice is strongly discouraged, except in the case of the automatic variables

It wouldn't work for, say, `FF` and `GG`.

So the normal way to write your makefile would be:

```
.PHONY: foo
export BANANA = I am a banana


foo: F=`./a.sh`
foo: G=$(shell ./a.sh)
foo:
    echo $(F)
    echo $(G)
```

which has exactly the same effect.

And this perhaps clarifies the difference between the output of `echo $(F)`
and `echo $(G)`.

`$(shell ./a.sh)` invokes a make function that executes `./a.sh` in a shell 
directly spawned by `make` and returns the `stdout` of so doing. Thus for target `foo`, make-variable `G` will
be defined as the `stdout` of executing `./a.sh` in a child shell of `make`.

`` `./a.sh` `` does not invoke any make-function. As far as make is concerned, it is just
a string. For the target `foo`, make-variable `F` will be defined as `` `./a.sh ` ``

The exported make-variable `BANANA` is not injected into the environment of a shell spawned by
 `$(shell ...)`. [5.7.2 Communicating Variables to a Sub-make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables_002fRecursion.html#Variables_002fRecursion)

> To pass down, or export, a variable, make adds the variable and its value to the 
>   environment for running each line of the recipe

An exported variable and its definition is only injected into the environments of the shells that
run the lines of recipes.

Thus `BANANA` is not defined in the environment of `a.sh` when it is run by `$(shell ./a.sh)`
to generate the definition of `G`. But it *is* defined in the environment of the shell
that that runs the recipe line `echo $(F)`, with `$(F)` = `` `a.sh` ``. That shell (not `make`) interprets
`` `a.sh` `` as a back-tick invocation of a subshell, which inherits the definition of
`BANANA`.

To get `BANANA` exported into the environment of `$(shell ...)`, you have to do
it yourself since it is not done by `make`:

```
G=$(shell export BANANA='$(BANANA)'; ./a.sh)
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  This is a well written description.  Unfortunately, the explicit export of variables in each invocation of `shell` is exactly the problem I'm trying to solve.  I find the documentation for make dishonest, where it states in reference to .EXPORT_ALL_VARIABLES: `Simply by being mentioned as a target, this tells 'make' to export all variables to child processes by default.`  A shell invoked by `shell` is certainly a child process!

Comment: @blitzen9872 gnu make is deceptively complicated. The more you learn about it the more nuanced you realize it is. The manual cannot footnote every single statement with a proviso to go and read a previous or subsequent chapter.

Comment: @Mort I'm not asking the documentation to reference a previous chapter, I'm pointing out that "this tells 'make' to export all variables to child processes by default" is inaccurate.  If there is another chapter that makes that correct, I would love a reference to it!