# Shell `if` in Makefile executing both branches

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I have the following rule in my Makefile compiled with GNU make 4.1:

```
multiboot_check: kernel.bin
    if [ $(grub2-file --is-x86-multiboot $^) -eq 0 ]; then \
        $(info $^: valid Multiboot Version 1 header); \
    else \
        $(error $^: invalid Multiboot Version 1 header); \
    fi
```

When I run this, both the true and false branch are executed, resulting in the following output:

```
kernel.bin: valid Multiboot Version 1 header
Makefile:24: *** kernel.bin: invalid Multiboot Version 1 header.  Stop.
```

Why is this occurring? Is there a better way?

I have tried putting it into a single line, and even reducing the if statement to `[ 0 -eq 0 ]`, and it still executes both branches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recipe is equivalent to:

```
multiboot_check: kernel.bin
#   `make` directives evaluated for this target are not part of the recipe
    $(info $^: valid Multiboot Version 1 header)
    $(error $^: invalid Multiboot Version 1 header)
#   The recipe is...
    if [ -eq 0 ]; then \
        ; \
    else \
        ; \
    fi
```

To understand first why `make` does not order the lines as you have written them,
read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41621328/1362568)

The residual recipe:

```
    if [ -eq 0 ]; then \
        ; \
    else \
        ; \
    fi
```

is syntactically invalid for the shell, because the unescaped `$(grub2-file ...)`
will be expanded by `make` and not the shell and will expand to nothing. You want
it to be a shell expansion, so you need to escape it for `make`:

```
$$(grub2-file...)
```

But although the residual recipe will provoke a shell syntax error, you
never see it, because `make` evaluates:

```
    $(info $^: valid Multiboot Version 1 header)
    $(error $^: invalid Multiboot Version 1 header)
```

before the recipe is run, and the `$(error ...)` directive terminates `make`
before it attempts to execute the invalid recipe.

Corrected for shell-expansion, the test:

```
[ $$(grub2-file --is-x86-multiboot $^) -eq 0 ]
```

will still fail to achieve what you apparently want. This test will
determine whether the standard output of the command `grub2-file --is-x86-multiboot kernel.bin`
is a string equal to `0`. Presumably it never will be and what you actually
want to determine is whether the exit code of the command is 0.

In the light of all this, a better way is:

```
multiboot_check: kernel.bin
    grub2-file --is-x86-multiboot $^; \
    if [ $$? -eq 0 ]; then \
        echo "$^: valid Multiboot Version 1 header"; \
    else \
        echo "$^: invalid Multiboot Version 1 header"; exit 1; \
    fi
```